# Can't update array with function?

Tags: php, arrays, function

```
$LEVELS = array();

function addLevel() {
    $LEVELS[1] = "test";
}

var_dump($LEVELS);
```

It  prints

```
array(0) {
}
```

This is annoying the crap out of me. Any help?

Comment: you call the function addLevel in your code?

Comment: Read up about "variable scope" - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @yoda - don't propogate bad practises, global is not the best answer... pass as a function argument instead, and either pass by reference or use a return

Answer (score 6):

```
$LEVELS = array();

function addLevel() {
    global $LEVELS;
    $LEVELS[1] = "test";
}


addLevel(); // CALL YOUR FUNCTION
var_dump($LEVELS);
```

That said, this is a better way:

```
$LEVELS = array();

function addLevel(&$LEVELS) { // This is a pass by reference -- points to the same array
    $LEVELS[1] = "test";
}


addLevel($LEVELS); // CALL YOUR FUNCTION
var_dump($LEVELS);
```

Or ...

```
$LEVELS = array();

function addLevel($LEVELS) { // THis gets a copy of the array
    $LEVELS[1] = "test";
    return $LEVELS;          //and send it back
}


$LEVELS = addLevel($LEVELS); // CALL YOUR FUNCTION
var_dump($LEVELS);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your function first to make its code do anything (and you got just function body somewhere in your code - it does not mean it will be executed). You do not seem to do that. But even you fix this, it will still not work, because you'd working on variables in **scope** of function (aka local variables). There's is NO $LEVELS array in your function, not the other one is visible inside. So your line `$LEVELS[1] = "Test";` simply **creates new array** visible in scope of function.

To solve your issue you should pass you array to function **by reference**:

```
function addLevel( &$myArray ) {
  $myArray[1] = "test";
}
```

then pass your array:

```
addLevel( $LEVELS );
```

you can also use `global` but this is **WRONG** so do not do that.

Answer (score 1):

Use "global" in function, if you wan't to access $LEVEL variable.

```
$LEVELS = array();
function addLevel() {
    global $LEVELS;
    $LEVELS[1] = "test";
}
addLevel();
var_dump($LEVELS);
```

Comment: And one more thing, `addLevel()` should be called before `var_dump`

Answer (score 1):

It's a [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue.

You need to either pass your variable in as a parameter:

```
// declare array in global scope
$LEVELS = array(); 
// define function that takes array as parameter     
function addLevel($LEVELS) { 
    $LEVELS[1] = "test";
    return $LEVELS;
}
// execute function, pass array to function scope using parameter
$LEVELS = addLevel($LEVELS);
// show contents
var_dump($LEVELS);
```

Or declare it as a global variable:

```
// declare array in global scope
$LEVELS = array(); 
// define function
function addLevel() { 
    // import array from global scope
    global $LEVELS;
    $LEVELS[1] = "test"; 
}
// execute function
addLevel();
// show contents
var_dump($LEVELS);
```

For clarity and to keep the global variable space as empty as possible, the first example (passing as parameter) is usually preferred.